# Change Makefile variable value depending on a target

Tags: makefile

I am not proficient with makefiles, but am used to simple ones. Right now, I have a task on hand.

I need to compile and link a test application with a different library and different include path based on the given target. If target is TARGET1, then link against LIB1 and include INCLUDEPATH1 during compilation. Similarly, if given target is TARGET2, then compile with INCLUDEPATH2 in CFLAGS and link with LIB2.

```
%.o: %.c
    @echo [CC]  $< ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $*.o $<
```

Now I have a rule as above which compiles my test application. Now how can the CFLAGS be changed based on the target.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make, you can use [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
target1: CFLAGS = -IINCLUDEPATH1
target1: LDLIBS = -lLIB1

target2: CFLAGS = -IINCLUDEPATH2
target2: LDLIBS = -lLIB2

all: target1 target2

target1: target1.o misc.o
target2: target2.o
```

However this doesn't work quite as well as you'd like: if *target1* and *target2* share some source files, you'll need to arrange for them to each be compiled twice and to differently-named .o files -- which will rather complexify your makefile.

Also, if you type `make target1` then `-IINCLUDEPATH1` will be propagated to the compilation of *misc.c*, as desired.  However if you type `make misc.o` it has no way to know that this is eventually destined for *target1* and the compilation of *misc.c* will get no special $CFLAGS value (though it'll get the global one, if there is one).

So this is really only useful in simple cases.  But maybe your case is sufficiently simple.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that target-specific variables are propagated to implicit rules!

Comment: Great advice. Even though I've been writing Makefiles for too long, somehow I was never aware of this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can alter variable depending on a target.  Assume you invoke

```
make TARGET1 TARGET2
```

What value would the `CFLAGS` have then?

In this case, you can use non-pattern rules to distinguish targets.

```
TARGET1: a.c
    @echo [CC] $< ...
    $(CC) -I INCLUDEPATH1 ...

TARGET2: a.c
    @echo [CC] $< ...
    $(CC) -I INCLUDEPATH2 ...
```

To decrease repetition, you may also use variables and "[functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function)".  Then, you could re-use what would be the body of your pattern rule in different rules.

```
define compile_cmd
    @echo [CC] $< ...
    $(CC) -I $1 -l$2 $(CFLAGS)
endef

TARGET1: a.c
    $(call compile_cmd,INCLUDEPATH1,LIB1) -o $@ $<

TARGET2: a.c
    $(call compile_cmd,INCLUDEPATH2,LIB2) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(call compile_cmd,INCLUDEPATH_DEFAULT,LIB_DEFAULT) -o $@ $<
```

That would make a nice enough and flexible makefile that suits your needs.